# Помогите с добавлением элементов во вложенный список

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужна помощь с созданием вложенного списка. Вот мой первоначальный код:

```
n = 5
arr = [[0 for i in range(2)] for j in range(n)]
```

Теперь мне нужно пройтись по всем вложенным спискам, и в 0-й элемент первого вложенного списка поставить число 1, а в последующие 0-е элементы вложенных списков увеличивать число на 2. Вот, что должно получиться:

```
[[1, 0], [3, 0], [5, 0], [7, 0], [9, 0]]
```

Я как только не вертел цикл for, теперь прошу Вашей помощи. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `[[i, 0] for i in range(1, n*2, 2)]` ?

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог -- галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. MaxU:

   ```
   [[i, 0] for i in range(1, n*2, 2)]
   ```
2. ```
   list(map(lambda el: [el, 0], range(1, n*2, 2)))
   ```